# Is there an integral representation for $\arctan(x) \zeta(2x)$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, riemann-zeta

I know there are integral representations for $\zeta(x) , \Gamma(x) $ and even $\zeta(x) \Gamma(x)$.

I wonder Is there an integral representation for $\arctan(x) \zeta(2x)$ ?

$\arctan(x) \zeta(2x) = \int_0^{\infty} g(x,t) dt$

Probably.

Comment: Does $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(2x)}\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{t^{2x-1}}{e^x-1}\,dx $$ count a such?

Comment: No , everything must be under the integral

Comment: Then $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(2x)}\iint_{(0,1)\times\mathbb{R}^+}\frac{x t^{2x-1}}{(1+x^2 t^2)(e^x-1)}\,dx\,dt $$ :D

Comment: A single integral.

Comment: I made a small edit